# what is the reason for following situation?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

what is the reason for it?
my code for this part:

```
<label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
      <small>Remember Me</small>
</label>
```

why crash check box and text as following image??

plz..help me.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: the reason is the CSS that you didn't share

Comment: fix the title of the question to something meaningful, a read on [ask] and [mcve] is highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the label inside `<div class="form-check">` would fix your issue.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-check">
<label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
      <small>Remember Me</small>
</label>
</div>
```